# How do i remove the element with lowest priority in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am working on a program in which  a priority queue extends a queue:

```
class PQueue: public Queue;
```

My `PQueue` list is enqueued using Queue's enqueue method, but I created a dequeue method for `PQueue` to remove items with minimum priority. Somehow i can't implement it.

If you have a pQueue like head[2 8 5 9 0 3 9 7]tail, The list would become 2 8 5 9 3 9 7, the 0 removed and stored in a variable for return. Pls help

Comment: Where's the code that demonstrates what you've tried?

Comment: *"How do i remove the element with lowest priority in C++"* - you usually do that with `pop`. See, for example, [`priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/). Where is the documentation for the `Queue` class you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for this. If you want to pop the smallest element first, use `std::greater` instead of `std::less` as comparison function object .